# Java Calendar generates invalid month and date

Tags: java, calendar

Plase have a look at the below code

```
 Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
            initialClientLetterDate.setText(date.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"/"+date.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"/"+date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

This generates the invalid "month" and "date". The output is  `2014/09/06`. Why is this? I just wanted to get current year, date and month.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using [`DAY_OF_WEEK`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) which is **6** for `FRIDAY`and [`MONTH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) starts from 0 not 1 so you have to add 1 in it.You can use [`DAY_OF_MONTH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_MONTH) instead of `DAY_OF_WEEK`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like as below code. You should not forgot to set locale.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
    System.out.println(date.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "/" 
            + (date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/"
            + date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DAY_OF_WEEK Returns an int (starting at 1?) for the day in the week so Friday would be 6, Month does the same except starting at 0 so 09 would be October.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK

Answer (score 0):

date.get(Calendar.YEAR)  =  Gives the current year 
date.get(Calendar.MONTH) =  Gives the month of the year as an integer from 0 to 11, where 0 = Jan and 11 = dec
date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) = Gives the day of the week from 0  to 6, where 0 = Monday

So if you want to get the current date you must do

```
date.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"/"+(date.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"/"+date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```